# Deployed Solution containing visual web part not showing up in Custom category

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2010

I have a Password Change visual web part that deploys and functions perfectly on my development server yet on the Integration/Test server the .wsp deploys yet does not show the web part in the pick list "Custom" category for any site.

Integration/Test Central Management Console .wsp file status:

Name: sp2010passwordchange.wsp
Type: Core Solution
Contains Web Application Resource: Yes
Contains Global Assembly: Yes
Contains Code Access Security Policy: No
Deployment Server Type: Front-end Web server
Deployment Status: Deployed
Deployed To: https://portal2.mysite.com/
Last Operation Result: The solution was successfully deployed.
Last Operation Details: MYCOMPANY-SP10 : https://portal2.mysite.com/ : The solution was successfully deployed.
Last Operation Time: 7/12/2010 3:05 PM

Elements file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
     <Module Name="PasswordChange" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
       <File Path="PasswordChange\PasswordChange.webpart" Url="PasswordChange.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
         <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
       </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Also -- the web part does not show up the the web part gallery as well.

---

So my questions are:
 What are the most common reasons for this failure?
 Am I missing some additional Site deployment steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you deployed the solution package did you activate the Feature that adds your Web Part to the Web Part gallery (it will be in Site Collection Features)? This is done for you automatically by the deployment tools in Visual Studio but you need to do it manually when you deploy to production.

**Update (June 15, 2016)**: I recorded a video that walks through the process of deploying a farm solution containing a web part. [Deploying a Farm Solution Containing Web Parts to SharePoint 2013 or 2016](https://youtu.be/UOsEo6E0iA4)

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I was able to find the Site Collection Feature list under the Site Settings menu and activate the feature.  I knew I was missing something -- as usual I was digging too deep for my solution.

Comment: @rob: I am facing the same issue. Web part is not showing up in my web part gallery on Production Environment. However all the web part is visible in DEV environment.  I have already activated the feature for this custom web part. Is there are particular settings that i need to verify ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recorded a video that walks through the process of deploying a farm solution containing a web part. I've added a link to the video to my answer

Answer (score 2):

The feature did not automatically show up in the site collection for me. After deploying the solution in the “SharePoint 2010 Management Shell” with

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename XXXXXXXX.wsp
```

I had to activate the feature for my site collection with

```
enable-spfeature -Identity ProjName_FeatureName -url http://myserver/sites/ZZZZ
```

The feature name can be found in your .package file manifest

> <Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" ...>
>
> ...
>
> <FeatureManifests>
>
> <FeatureManifest Location="**ProjName_FeatureName**\Feature.xml"
>   />
>
> </FeatureManifests> </Solution>